# How can I attach a paragraph to a node using hook_node_update()?

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to attach a paragraph whose value comes from a custom field to a node, in `hook_node_update()`.

I tried with two different implementations. Neither of those work.

```php
function my_module_node_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  $paragraph = Paragraph::create([
    'type' => 'attendance',
    'field_stakeholder' => array(
      "value"  =>  '. Roshni, UPS Kharwna from Dunda, Uttarkashi (UTK_130000377) (49645)',
    ),
  ]);
    
  $paragraph->save(); 
    
  dpm($paragraph->id());
    
  $current[] = array(
    'target_id' => $paragraph->id(),
    'target_revision_id' => $paragraph->getRevisionId(),
  );

  $entity->set('field_attendance', $current);  
  $entity->save();
}
```

```php
function my_module_node_update(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
  $paragraph = Paragraph::create([
    'type' => 'attendance',
    'field_stakeholder' => array(
      "value"  =>  '. Roshni, UPS Kharwna from Dunda, Uttarkashi (UTK_130000377) (49645)',
    ),
  ]);
    
  $paragraph->save(); 
    
  dpm($paragraph->id());
    
  $entity->field_attendance->appendItem($paragraph);
  $entity->save();
}
```

However, I am getting an error.

> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
> constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '213436' for key 'PRIMARY':
> INSERT INTO {node_revision} (nid, vid, langcode, revision_timestamp,
> revision_uid, revision_log) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0,
> :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2,
> :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4,
> :db_insert_placeholder_5); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 41374
> [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 213436 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => en
> [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 1535117690 [:db_insert_placeholder_4] =>
> 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => ) in
> Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 777 of
> /home/rupali/fa-rupali/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).

I feel like the error is coming as the hook is called twice. The code works until the paragraph creation. I am able to verify it.

Comment: Did you try remove **$entity->save();** in **method 1**?

Comment: Why do you need to do this in a update hook which runs after already saving the host entity? If possible in any way, you should do it in hook_node_presave() so you don't have to save the etntiy again